# Zebra ZPL-II: How to revert ^CIx,... settings

Tags: printing, zpl-ii

we have a new set of labels generated with Zebra-printers. For the new labels, I use extensive character replacements in the ^CIx,... command.
(Most silly one I actually *need* is this: ^CI6,91,91,92,92,93,93,123,123,124,124,125,125)

For the new labels, everything works just fine.
But when I want to print some of the old labels, things get a little mixed up.
First of all, the old labels don't use any ^CI command, so I *assume* they were printing in ^CI0 (back in the times before the new labels came in). I don't know, though.
The best way, whatsoever, would be to just revert all ^CI settings to power-on state (but *not* reverting any other printer-settings).
I have read about ~JR command, but it goes a few steps too far for what I want to do.
Does anyone know a way to just reset the ^CI configuration?

Thanks in advance!
Regards,
Pelle.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the old labels, you should just add a `^CI0` at the beginning. From the Zebra Programming Guide:

> We recommend that a ^CI command (or Unicode BOM) is included at the beginning of each
>   ZPL script. This is important when ZPL scripts with different encodings are being sent to a
>   single printer.

If you can't alter the old labels, you can send a separate (empty) label to the printer prior to printing old labels:

`^XA^CI0^XZ`